# NodeJS - sqlite3, data synchronization

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, synchronization

I'm trying to write a simple app with nodejs, socket.io and sqlite as a database.
This is mostly for training purpose at the moment, to learn how nodejs works and see if it would be suitable for another project.

The app is a simple page with a single button.
The database is used to store the status of the button (on/off). //This is a requirement because this db would be accessible by other services
Basically, the page shows the current status (last record in the db)
When the button is clicked,  the status is changed, and the new status is added to the database.
This seems to work and the db is updated.

Now, I'd like to make these changes visual by using the color of the button to display the current status.
For example, blue when it's OFF and red when it's ON.
I tried to use socket.io for handling the click event and it seems I can change the color of the button, when clicking on it.

But the color is gone if the page is refreshed (and it seems I need to refresh the page to see the updated value in the database)

How can I keep a page content (data displayed and color of the button) synchronized with the database ?

I hope someone can point me to the right direction.
Thanks,

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mainDB = 'data/mydb';
var hbs = require('hbs');

var app = express();
//all environments
app.set('port', 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

function getStatus(database, callback){
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(database);
    // Get the last record
    db.get("SELECT * FROM status ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", function(err, all) {
        console.log("Current status..."+all.status);
        callback(err, all);
    });
    db.close();
}
function setStatus(database, status){
    console.log("Set Status..."+status);
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(database);
    db.run("INSERT INTO status(status, time) VALUES(?,?)", status, Date.now());
    db.close();
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    getStatus(mainDB,function(err, json_value) {
        res.render('index',{title:"Test", status:json_value.status,time:json_value.time});
    });

});


var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('click', function(htmlID){
        getStatus(mainDB,function(err, json_value) {
            console.log("Button clicked, current status: "+json_value.status)
            setStatus(mainDB, !json_value.status);
            io.sockets.emit('updateButton',htmlID); 
        });
    });

});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Client.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var socket = io.connect();

    $('.box').click(function () {
        var selectedID = $(this).attr("id");
        socket.emit('click', selectedID);
        updateButton(selectedID);
    });


    function updateButton(selectedID) {
        $("#" + selectedID).css({
            "background": "red"
        });
    }

    socket.on('updateButton', function (selectedID) {
        updateButton(selectedID);
    });
});
```

views/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/client.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <p>Status: {{status}}</p>
            <p>Time: {{time}}</p>
              <div class="box" id="alarm">{{status}}</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

A .py to create the dummy db:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import date, datetime
import sqlite3
import time

tables = {
    'status' : '''
    CREATE TABLE status(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    status INTEGER,
    time  TIMESTAMP)
    '''
    }

def create_db():
    db = sqlite3.connect("data/mydb")
    with db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        for tb_name, create_statement in tables.iteritems():
            cursor.execute('drop table if exists %s'%tb_name)
            print "Creating table : %s"%tb_name
            cursor.execute(create_statement)
            db.commit()

        # fake up some data
        status = 0
        for i in range(10):
            status = not status
            default_values = [status, datetime.now() ]
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO status(status, time) values(?,?)', default_values)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        db.commit()
    db.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_db()
```

Comment: A side note. You mentioned that you plan to use sqlite with other programs. By design sqlite is made to be used only by a single program at a time. Eventhough it is SQL, the implementation is still - reading and writing to a local file. Use it by two programs, and you will run into raise conditions or file corruption quickly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm aware this could be a problem. But it won't be an issue in this case. Only one process will make changes to the database at any moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Sqlite module are made for "in memory database", so when you write any INSERT statement it won't be committed until you write it to the disk.

I'm working with electron and sql.js (sqlite3 node is not working in electron)
and the only solution i've found is to run the query (INSERT ...), export the db (sql.js has db.export() method) and then overwrite the file using filesystem.